# Какие 2 параметра должны быть в запросе при переходе на php7?

Tags: php7, php5

> ERROR Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in Database.php on line 35

Не подходят:

```
$res = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$res = mysqli_query($db, $query);
$res = mysqli_query($sql, $query);


public function get_all_db() {
    $sql = "SELECT id,title,discription FROM statti LIMIT 10";

    $res = mysqli_query($db, $query);

    if(!$res) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    for ($i = 0;$i < mysqli_num_rows($res); $i++) {
        $row[] = mysqli_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_ASSOC);
    }

    return $row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$db = mysqli_connect('addr:3307', 'root', 'pass') or die('Error connect');

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `table`';

$query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

$res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
```

Если подключение удалось, все должно работать.

Comment: у вас ош. синт. была $query. но даже если заменить, то: Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Comment: Ошибку исправил. Ну да, у вас будет такая ошибка, вы сами должны создать запрос к своей таблице.

Comment: @ Евгений Иванов так запрос есть `$sql = "SELECT id, title, discription FROM statti";` и далее `$res = mysqli_query($db, $query);`  после чего на этой стр  mysqli_query() mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given

Comment: Оно пишет что первый параметр(подключения) равен `null` Это значит что не получилось подключиться к базе.

Comment: Это значит что человек про области видимости переменных не знает.